# Особенности работы дженериков в Java

Tags: java, ооп, generics

Прежде чем отвечать, прошу вдумчиво прочитать и осмыслить вопрос.
Итак у нас есть такой код, он скомпилируется и никаких ошибок не будет:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method(4,"s");
}

static <K> void method(K k1, K k2) {

}
```

Я думал, что логически ошибка должна быть, ну раз нет, значит такие особенности джавы. Далее, есть такой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method(new ArrayList<Executor>(), new Object());
}

static <K> void method(List<K> k, K k2) {

}
```

Этот код уже выдает ошибку компиляции. Компилятор говорит, что я в `method (List<Executor>, java.util.concurrent.Executor)` засовываю не то, что надо. Действительно, `Object` это вам не `Executor`. Но вот теперь **главный мой вопрос** почему в первом случае компилятору пофиг, что одному и тому же параметризованному типу присваиваются разные типы данных, а во втором случае компилятор на основе первого аргумента метода вычисляет какой должен быть аргумент второго метода. Я не понимаю какая логика работает в обоих случаях.

И еще один не менее важный вопрос, если немного изменить второй пример кода вот так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method(new ArrayList<Executor>(), 150);
}

static <K> void method(List<? extends K> k, K k2) {

}
```

Теперь никакой ошибки не возникает, причем мы можем пихать любые типы данных а компилятору все равно! Мы всего лишь изменили `List<K>` на `List<? extends K>`. Тут я уже даже теряюсь, что это значит. Лист который содержит что-то, что наследует `К`, а что такое `К`? И почему в итоге нам разрешено класть в параметры метода что угодно (напоминаю, что в предыдущем примере с листом это не разрешено).

Comment: @Regent javac 1.8.0._131, не компилируется, ожидаемо выводит ошибку несоответствия типов

Comment: @etki это ж я писал ровно тогда же, когда и под вашим ответом отписывался. То бишь тогда, когда неправильно "срисовал" второй пример. Когда свою ошибку понял, все лишние комментарии потёр.

Answer (score 4):

Границы для параметров параметризованных типов работают несколько иначе, нежели для простых типов. В первом случае оба типа могут быть приведены к Object, во втором случае тип может быть только либо Object, либо Executor. Если просто тип может быть легко "снижен" до объекта, то дженерики в параметризованных типах такое по умолчанию не позволяют - пока вы не укажете `? extends K`, разрешающее использование наследников K, или `? super K`, разрешающее использование предков K. В данном случае вы указали `? extends K`, что позволяет использовать Object вместо K, таким образом список параметров метода формируется как `List<? extends Object>, Object`.

Могу быть в чем-то неправ, точные ответы на эти вопросы содержатся в JLS (Java Language Specification)

Comment: @Regent `List<K>`

Comment: @Regent в смысле идентичны? В одном просто дженерик, в другом параметризованный тип с дженериком.

Comment: Пардон - это я промахнулся при переносе. Пошел смотреть на коррекный вариант.

Comment: @Regent в JLS сходу найти не могу, но https://stackoverflow.com/a/2660850/2908793

Comment: Да, в принципе, всё сводится к тому, что во втором случае в качестве `K` нельзя взять ни `Object` (так как нельзя передать `List<Executor>` как `List<Object>`), ни `Executor` (так как `new Object()` не является `Executor`-ом).